# protractor what does the timeout in expected conditions stand for?

Tags: protractor

Protractor: Version 1.8.0

```
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), 3000);
```

what exactly does the 3 seconds stand for? and is there an error thrown when 3 seconds have passed and element cannot be found? or does the test just continue?

I ran a test with:

```
element(by.id('#input')).sendKeys('foo');    
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath(BAD-LOCATOR)), 3000));
element(by.id('#input')).sendKeys('bar');
```

BAD-LOCATOR is just a xpath referencing a element that doesn't exists. but upon evaluating this line, the test waits beyond this time until it hits the jasmine defaultTimeoutInterval timeout (I set for 25sec). Why does it not fail in 3 secs since the promise did not get resolved in 3secs? I'm expecting the wait() to fail and the 2nd sendKeys command to execute since its next in control flow.

So the above block of code will print 'foo' into the textbox and on the next command wait until the jasmine timeout to error out (Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.). I'm expecting an error within 3secs. 'bar'never gets printed.

Comment: it should timeout at 3s. You sure it wasn't waiting at a line prior to the browser.wait?

Comment: @hankduan, yes i'm sure. if I modify the bad locator to a valid locator and rerun, the test continues.

Comment: I just tried it and works for me. Can you specify a) version of protractor, b) what is `BAD-LOCATOR` and c) what is `elem`? Here's what I tried for reference (please use http{colon}//www.angularjs.org instead of copying the shortened version):

browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('bad-locator')), 3000);

Comment: @hankduan. thank you for reply. I will update my original post to answer your questions.

Comment: I think `browser.wait()` also accepts a third argument, which is a String corresponding to an error message that will be displayed if the wait times out. If you add that argument, does the error message display?

Answer (score 0):

It's the time out, i mean after 3 seconds if the element isn't present until now it will time out. 
For the jasmine error you are getting i suggest that you add the call back

```
 describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      done();
    }, 1000);
```

You can also refer to [Jasmine Asynchronous Support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)